# Convert old AnimationNodes to Current - a flying away movement - what is the "Objects from Group" replacement

Tags: animation, add-on, animation-nodes

How to convert this animation to current 2.8x animation nodes ?
A simple flying with slight rotation, controlled by the empty locaion....

[image]

I can't find a kind of "Objects from Collection" node

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thanks so @OmarEmaraDev it's called "Collection Info" now,
also it kind of messed up the the inital transforms and Index Keys